# Can Coderay re-indent C (or C-like) code?

Tags: javascript, ruby, code-formatting, coderay

I've got a site that accepts input from newbie coders, and would like to re-indent code so that it is "properly" formatted. I'd be happy with re-indenting the code as it's displayed, so it could be a ruby solution, but might also be interested in a JS solution if it could show the user the results before saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. CodeRay is only for syntax highlighting. It doesn't include a proper parser.

Comment: Any suggestions for a Ruby or JS friendly solution instead?